# How to use Runtime.exec() with backslash?

Tags: java, runtime

I try to start an shell script from a detached screen in java.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screen -S " + code + " -X stuff \"bash start.sh $(printf \\\\r)\"");
```

I think a `"` is replaced with `\"` and `\` with `\\`.

The normal code which should be executed is

```
screen -S VMD54 -X stuff "bash start.sh $(printf \\r)"
```

That starts *start.sh* from the detached screen e.g. *VMD54* (String code).

What is wrong with my code? Nothing happens in the screen *VMD54*.

Comment: The command passed to exec is broken into tokens using the StringTokenizer as per documentation, I would suggest to you try build your command testing it directly on StringTokenizer

Comment: Docs in here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)

Comment: Use a `ProcessBuilder` instead.

Comment: Don't use `Runtime.exec`. Use a `ProcessBuilder`, pass each parameter separately, and put your bash command as a single parameter - you will not need the (extra) backslashes or the quote.

Comment: Also, you are trying to use a bash construct `$(printf \\r)` - this won't work when you are running it from Java rather than bash. You can possibly just pass `\r` instead - though it seems suspicious to me that you need to pass a shell script a control character as parameter.

Comment: Tried `String[] commands = {"screen", "-S", code, "-X", "stuff", "bash start.sh\r"};`. Thanks! Works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use `ProcessBuilder` than `exec`. Either way, use the version that uses separate parameters. This is because the version that uses one long string does not break that string the way you think - it mostly just breaks it on spaces and disregards the quotes, passing them as part of the command.

When you do that, you should consider that what you write on the command line is not what the process actually receives in the end. The command line interpreter - bash in your case - does several things. It expands stuff that begins with `$`. It removes the quotes but treats everything inside them as one parameter. So when you have the command:

```
screen -S VMD54 -X stuff "bash start.sh $(printf \\r)"
```

What bash does is break it into words removing the quotes (the quotes mark that the whole `bash start.sh...` thing is one "word").

```
 screen
 -S
 VMD54
 -X
 stuff
 bash start.sh $(printf \\r)
```

Then interpret the `$` commands inside the separated words

```
 screen
 -S
 VMD54
 -X
 stuff
 bash start.sh ␍
```

It creates a process and passes these six parameters. And you should do exactly the same thing in Java, because Java does not have a bash interpreter built-in. To produce the carriage return character you should just use `\r` in Java

```
String[] arguments = { "screen", "-S", code, "-X", "stuff", "bash start.sh \r" };
```

Comment: Got it, like I said in the comment before. Thanks alot :)